# Allow preview in macOS of video created using ffmpeg lossless command

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png, lossless

I'm using ffmpeg 4.4 to make a slideshow video that is lossless from png images like so:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i 'image_%05d.png' -c:v libx264 -crf 0 out.mp4
```

The only thing is that in macOS Finder, preview is not available. Normally the video icon is a frame from the video and you can play it in Finder. The video generated with the command however just shows my default video player icon and you cannot preview. If you open in VLC it plays fine. Adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` shows the preview, but this degrades the video quality.

Comment: See if it prefers PNG muxed into MOV: `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i 'image_%05d.png' -c:v copy out.mov`

Comment: @llogan There was still no macOS Finder preview and the file could not be opened by QuickTime either using that command.